# php 5.4 compiling: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-fastcgi

Tags: php, compiler-warnings, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to install php 5.4.14 on my ubuntu 10.04 server.
I need the fastcgi option to be able to run two php versions.

This is my configuration:

> `./configure '--with-libdir=lib64' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--prefix=/usr/local/php540-cgi' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php540-cgi/etc' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--enable-fastcgi' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi' '--with-openssl' '--with-pspell' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-zlib' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-wddx' '--with-kerberos' '--with-unixODBC=/usr' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite3' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-imap' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-gd' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-ldap' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysqli' '--with-snmp' '--enable-soap' '--with-xsl' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--enable-pdo' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-pdo-pgsql' '--with-pear=/usr/local/php540-cgi/pear' '--with-mcrypt' '--enable-intl' '--without-pdo-sqlite' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php540-cgi/php.d'`

I'm getting now this error message and I have no clue what's wrong/missing:

> WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-fastcgi

Comment: In case this was a google request, the answer might be: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48926

Comment: Sorry, no it wasn't. I found out that --enable-fastcgi is always on and can't be switched of. Therefore this argument isn't supported anymore. 
Anyway. Thx for trying to help!

Comment: Yes, I tried to review more but ran out of time. Was already suspecting this is not your case but wasn't 100% sure so left the pointer. And please leave the answer below and accept it later. This will mark this as solved and next time somebody searches the error message here, there is the link to the ticket and your answer ;)